# Hardware won't boot, works fine afterwards as a USB disk

Tags: hard-drive, boot, usb, motherboard, sata

I have a 2TB Toshiba 3.5" hard drive.

When connected up to the motherboard during boot (either by SATA or USB) the motherboard (ASUS Sabertooth 990FX) will freeze on the motherboard logo and the BOOT_DEVICE_LED will light, indicating a problem loading the disk. When connected after boot via USB, the hard drive works perfectly, with no detectable issues.

What's going on here?

Edit: It may be of note that this is a new issue. This spontaneously started happening after a reboot a couple weeks ago, after maybe two years of flawless operation.

Comment: If bios allows you, disable quick boot. Normally this enables POST booting. which should display information about your hardware. Also check any other settings in your bios to ensure they are correct while in there, and see there are no other options for POST booting. This could provide you with more information in what it is doing when booting up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure your HDD is ok and works fine.
2. If possible, wipe the Hard Drive. If you already installed something, check that Operating System on another computer.
3. Make sure your Mainboard is set to GPT instead of MBR.

Comment: The hard drive does not contain the operating system, it's a storage drive only. It can be mounted by both Arch Linux and Windows 10 as a USB disk after boot.

Comment: It appears the GPT partition table was partially corrupt and this was causing the issue.